# Limit with indeterminate form

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

What is $${\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}} \frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e+\frac{ex}2}{x^2}$$ Here's what I tried $$\text {ATTEMPT}$$ We know that ${\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}} (1+h)^{1/h}=e$ so the $e.-e$ get cancelled  out now we want ${\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}} \frac{ex/2}{x^2}$ which is $\infty$ but it isn't in any option given. So please tell me any approximation or any better way to evaluate it.

Comment: What does it mean $h$?

Comment: Sorry its x ill edit

Comment: By imposing that the solution should not use l'Hospital's theorem you make the problem much more difficult than it really is.

Comment: I agree: the numerator is a Taylor expansion, so that algebraic tricks or fundamental limits seem to be insufficient.

Comment: It is in my book in sidenote

Comment: @Archis Should ${\lim_{\color{red}{x}\rightarrow 0}} (1+h)^{1/h}=e$ be ${\lim_{\color{red}{h}\rightarrow 0}} (1+h)^{1/h}=e$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The limit of $((1+x)^{1/x} - e+ ex/2)/x^2$ as $x\to 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879430/the-limit-of-1x1-x-e-ex-2-x2-as-x-to-0)

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{\ln((1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}})}=e^{1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}...}$$
$$=e.e^{-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}...}$$
$$=e\Big[1+\Big(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}...\Big)+\Big(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}...\Big)^2 +...\Big]$$
$$=e\Big[1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{11x^2}{24}...\Big]$$

$$\therefore \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{x^2}=\frac{11e}{24}$$

Comment: Nice method (+1) but you could improve it a little by showing the intermediate steps of how you got to $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{x^2}=\dfrac{11e}{24}$. As it is a pretty big jump.