# Finding $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{x^2}$ without using series expansion.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, exponential-function

> Finding $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{x^2}$ without using series expansion.

I am trying to solve it  using D L Hopital Rule

So $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}\bigg[\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)\bigg]+\frac{e}{2}}{2x}$

again i want to Diff with r to $x,$ but this is to complex

please help me how to short my calculation , Thanks

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In case it helps, I often use a bookmarklet so that I do not have to retype (or copy-paste) the formula into Approach0: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148/2018/7/4 Although even without the bookmarklet, just clicking on raw query and copy-paste is probably fast enough.

Comment: It's not duplicate of course! It's absolutely another problem.

Comment: We also have [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1735879/11619)

Answer (score 3):

The hint:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)\right)+\frac{ex^2}{2}}{2x^3}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\left((1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e\right)\left(\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)\right)+e\left(\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)\right)+\frac{ex^2}{2}}{x^3}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(-\frac{e}{2}\right)\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{2}{3}e\right)=\frac{11e}{24}.$$

Comment: Hi, I think the first equality is supposed to be true because $2x\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)\right)+\frac{ex^2}{2}}\to 1$. But it seems to me that $x\frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)\right)+\frac{ex^2}{2}}\to 1$. So I request your help in understanding what I am missing in understanding why there should be a 2 in the denominator after the first equality. Thanks.